# Angular 2 unit test

Tags: unit-testing, angular, jasmine

Got a couple of problems with my unit testing with Jasmine. First one:

I need to test this in a Component called CaseList:

```ts
gotoDetail(case: Case){
  this._router.navigate(['CaseDetail', {"id": case.id}]);
}
```

All my attempts at the tests give the error is this._router is undefined, well that's because I haven't defined it in my test, as I can't figure out how! I haven't even come up with any good attempts at the tests, as I have no idea how to proceed. So that's why I haven't posted any attempt here...

Edit: The part in the router-test which is related to to the problem above, but I test all the routing in a separate file! This test works!

```ts
it('Should navigate to Case Detail List', (done) => {   
router.navigate(['CaseDetail', {id: 'test'}]).then(() => {
        expect(location.path()).toEqual('/casedetail/test');
        done();
    }).catch(e => done.fail(e));
});
```

Second tests from a Detail Component (where user is navigated after choosing case) :

```ts
addStep(){
  this.case.getSteps().push(new Step());
}
```

I also have a remove method I need to test:

```ts
removeStep(step: Step){
  this.case.removeStep(step);
}
```

Constructor for this component:

```ts
constructor(public _routeParams: RouteParams, public _service: Service) {
  this.case = _service.getById(_routeParams.get('id'));
}
```

So the test I tried doing for the add-method:

```ts
it('passes new step to case-class', () => {
  spyOn(case, 'addStep')
  .and.returnValue(Observable.of({complete: true}))
  caseDetail.addStep();
  expect(case.addStep).toHaveBeenCalledWith(step);
});
```

So these methods call the methods that are in a separate class called "Case".

The error I'm getting when testing these are that case is null. I guess the routing and service messes it up, as in the same Component I have a other "identical" methods, and testing those works fine. But they belong to a different class.

Method in same component, referring to a "Step"-class:

```ts
addFeedback(step: Step){
  step.addFeedback(new Feedback());
}
```

The testing works perfectly:

```ts
it('passes feedback value to Step class', () => {
  spyOn(step, 'addFeedback')
  .and.returnValue(Observable.of({complete: true}))
  caseDetail.addFeedback(step);
  expect(step.addFeedback).toHaveBeenCalledWith(feedback);
})
```

So obviously in testing the component I should have everything defined that is needed, since the testing of the feedback method works. I just need to define the "case" object somehow, so that it doesn't complain about it being null.

Well hopefully you get my problem at hand and hopefully you can help! :)

Answer (score 1):

For your test cases to work, you will have to add router and case as a provider before the test.

Routing Example:

```
import {RootRouter} from 'angular2/src/router/router';
import {Location, RouteParams, Router, RouteRegistry, ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT} from 'angular2/router';
import {SpyLocation} from 'angular2/src/mock/location_mock';
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';

describe('Router', () => {
  let location, router;

  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    RouteRegistry,
    provide(Location, {useClass: SpyLocation}),
    provide(Router, {useClass: RootRouter}),
    provide(ROUTER_PRIMARY_COMPONENT, {useValue: App}),
  ]);

  beforeEach(inject([Router, Location], (_router, _location) => {
    router = _router;
    location = _location;
  }));

  it('Should be able to navigate to Home', done => {
    router.navigate(['Index']).then(() => {
      expect(location.path()).toBe('');
      done();
    }).catch(e => done.fail(e));
  });
});
```

Case Provider:

```
  import {Case} from '../case';

  beforeEachProviders(() => [
    provide(case, Case)
  ]);
```

Comment: I do have separate test for the Router, practically identical to your example. That works fine. I'm unsure what you mean "add router and case as a provider before the test". I'm really new to coding, and this is my first attempt to unit testing ;) Added the route test related to my first "problem" - "gotodetail" in my original question. As said the route test works fine! But I need to test the "gotodetail" in the component, and I am unsure how to define the router there? Do I really need to add all that code there, to be able to test "gotodetail"?

Comment: Or do I need to test "goToDetail" at all, since the route is tested? I'm a bit confused I guess. And the second problem also remains, case being null, so if anyone has any insights to that, that would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: If you are navigating through routes inside your unit test, then yes you will need all the code there. For case being null, I am not too sure what case is but you can try adding case as a provider before the unit test